# Consecutive reading of files in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 13 files with the extension .Las. Each has 80 columns and 180 thousand lines.

I need to read my files sequentially one after the other: the first, then the second, and so on.

Next is my script, in which I process data from files.

At the end, the program must output the data to the file with the same extension.

Thank you in advance for your response!!!

### And i programming in pandas, Jupyter notedook

```
cols = ['IK05', 'IK20', 'DA20', 'LLS', 'LLD', 'STP']



  data = pd.read_table("data/1.las", delim_whitespace = True,na_values = '-999.25', index_col=False)



  ndata = data.STP_AX.as_matrix(columns=None)

  nstop = 1
  stop = 1
  for i in range(len(ndata)):
      if(ndata[i]>0.1):
         stop = 0
    ndata[i] = nstop
else:
    if(stop == 0):
        stop = 1
        nstop = nstop + 1

    nstop





     data.STP = ndata
     data.STP = ndata


      df = data[cols]


     df1 = df.groupby('STP')
      df1.head()

     dfp  = pd.DataFrame()


      for name, group in df1:
       df1 = df.groupby('STP')
      df1.head()
```

​
          dfp  = pd.DataFrame()
​
​
        for name, group in df1:
              #print(name)
              #print(group)
              k,p=stats.mstats.normaltest(group[5:-5])
              #print(p)
          dfp[name] = p

---

Comment: Why don't you write a for loop?

Comment: I wanted to, but my teacher said to put the DataFrame in the function and work with it already.

Comment: Can you show us something that you've already tried?

Comment: Oh sure, complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to create variables for each file name, write them all in a dict, I'm giving an example using 3 files-

```
d = ["file1.las", "file2.las", "file3.las"]
```

Assuming your output file is `output.Las`
open the file using `w+` that allows for writing and appending a file

```
output = open("output.las", 'w+')
```

now, you can use a `for` loop to open each file, process it and then output the data into the output file

```
for i in d:
    file = open(i, 'r')
    contents = file.read()
    *your processing here*
    output.write(processedData)
    file.close()
```

Finally, you might want to close the output file:
`output.close()`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just new in programming and the first time I use this forum :)

Comment: No issues. We all start somewhere! I'm a newbie too. Also, if you found what you were looking for and it solves your query, select the answer as an accepted answer so that others can locate the same easily.